# CSS - Set countdown timer to dynamic sizing based on webpage size (DKTP or MOBL)

Tags: css

Need to change the following code from set to dynamic to auto adjust to the webpage width. If a user is on a desktop or mobile phone. Any help would be greatly appreciated. In a time crunch for this..

I think the CSS needs to changed to percentages

```
{% if end_date != blank %}
<div class="timer">
  {% if title != blank %}
  <h4 class="timer__title">{{ title }}</h4>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="timer-display">
    <div class="timer-block">
      <span class="timer-block__num js-timer-days">00</span>
      <span class="timer-block__unit">Days</span>
    </div>
    <div class="timer-block">
      <span class="timer-block__num js-timer-hours">00</span>
      <span class="timer-block__unit">Hours</span>
    </div>
    <div class="timer-block">
      <span class="timer-block__num js-timer-minutes">00</span>
      <span class="timer-block__unit">Minutes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="timer-block">
      <span class="timer-block__num js-timer-seconds">00</span>
      <span class="timer-block__unit">Seconds</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<style>
/* styles for timer */
  .timer {
    /*background: #f6fafd;*/
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
 
  .timer--expired {
    display: none;
  }
 
  .timer__title {
    @extend .paragraph;
    text-align: center;
  }
 
  .timer-display {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
 
  .timer-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 10px;
 
    &:not(:last-child):after {
      content: ':';
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 3px;
    }
  }
 
  .timer-block__num,
  .timer-block__unit {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
</style>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
  var second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;
 
  var countDown = new Date('{{- end_date -}}').getTime(),
      x = setInterval(function() {
      var now = new Date().getTime(),
          distance = countDown - now;
    document.querySelector('.js-timer-days').innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
      document.querySelector('.js-timer-hours').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
    document.querySelector('.js-timer-minutes').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
    document.querySelector('.js-timer-seconds').innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);
    }, second)
</script>
{% endif %}
```

I have tried to change the CSS styling to percent instead of px but it is not working`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not done this already, use the following tag in your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also, use the unit `vw` (visual width) instead of percentage wherever you feel appropriate.

Percentage values are as compared to parent element properties, whereas `vw` values are as compared to the visible area, that is if we resize the window in a computer, the width also changes.

For example, `width: 100vw` sets the width of the element as 100% of visible area.

`width: 50vw` sets the width of the element as 50% of visible area.

Hope you find this useful!